# How does one use tflite_convert to quantize a network trained with a tf.estimator.Estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

[`tflite_convert`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_examples.md) is a python script used to invoke TOCO (TensorFlow Lite Optimizing Converter) to convert files from Tensorflow's formats to tflite-compatible files.

I am trying to generate a quantized TFlite model starting from a network I trained with an `Estimator`. The training code is pretty straightforward and I added the required modifications for fine-tuning the model as required in the [Fixed Point Quantization guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization):

```
def input_fn(mode, num_classes, batch_size=1):
  #[...]
  return {'images': images}, labels

def model_fn(features, labels, num_classes, mode):
  images = features['images']
  with tf.contrib.slim.arg_scope(net_arg_scope()):
    logits, end_points = build_net(...)

  if FLAGS.with_quantization:
    tf.logging.info("Applying quantization to the graph.")
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
      tf.contrib.quantize.create_eval_graph()

  tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=labels, logits=logits)
  total_loss = tf.losses.get_total_loss()    #obtain the regularization losses as well

  if FLAGS.with_quantization:
    tf.logging.info("Applying quantization to the graph.")
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
      tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph()

  # Configure the training op, etc [...]
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(...)

def main(unused_argv):
  regex = FINETUNE_LAYER_RE if not FLAGS.with_quantization else '^((?!_quant).)*$'
  ws_settings = tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings(FLAGS.pretrained_checkpoint, regex)

  # Create the Estimator
  estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=lambda features, labels, mode: model_fn(features, labels, NUM_CLASSES, mode),
    model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
    #config=run_config,
    warm_start_from=ws_settings)

  # Set up input functions for training and evaluation
  train_input_fn = lambda : input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, NUM_CLASSES, FLAGS.batch_size)
  eval_input_fn = lambda : input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL, NUM_CLASSES, FLAGS.batch_size)

  #[...]

  train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(...)
  eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(...)
  tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

The first problem I ran into is that it's impossible to simply continue the training using the latest checkpoint after adding the quantization operations. This is because quantization adds extra variables that won't be found in the checkpoint. I solved that writing a warm start spec that filters out all the new variables by name and using as warm start checkpoint the latest checkpoint from the training.

Now, I want to generate an evaluation graph to save (with the related variables) in order to then feed it to TOCO via the `tflite_convert` script.
I have tried converting one of the `SavedModel`s exported after every evaluation, but that raises the following error:

> Array conv0_bn/FusedBatchNorm, which is an input to the Relu operator
>   producing the output array cell_stem_0/Relu, is lacking min/max data,
>   which is necessary for quantization. Either target a non-quantized
>   output format, or change the input graph to contain min/max
>   information, or pass --default_ranges_min= and --default_ranges_max=
>   if you do not care about the accuracy of results.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

I don't know how to get the right `SavedModel` or a pair `GraphDef` + checkpoint (although the SavedModel is preferrable)
Has anyone tried to quantized an estimator model? How do you generate the quantized evaluation graph?

Comment: have you managed to get estimators working with quantization-aware training?

Comment: Not really. Quantized graphs got set aside for now as I didn't have the time yet to look more into it.